# How to check if HttpServletRequest getPart("...") is set or not

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I'm uploading a CSV file to a Java servlet.
My HTML form looks like this :

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="submitBt" id="submitBt">
</form>
```

In my servlet, I do the following to retrieve the file :

```
public void uploadCsv(HttpServletRequest request) {
request.getPart("file")
...
}
```

When a file is set, the servlet does its work and **everything is ok.**

My problem is, I have a second form in the same JSP.
So when a form is submitted, I want to test if the input named "file" containing the CSV file is set or not.

I tried the following :

```
if (req.getParameter("file") != null)
```

**Always false**

```
if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("file"))
```

**Always false too**

```
if (req.getPart("file") != null)
```

**Throws an exception if file not set**

Help! D:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forms parts are sent like a file to the server, so you can do this...

```
boolean isthereafile;
if(request.getPart("file").getSize()>0){
isthereafile = true;
}
if(request.getPart("file").getSize()<=0){
isthereafile = false;
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, it is far better than mine :)

Comment: That's nitpicking, but getSize() never returns a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your servlet with `@MultipartConfig` in order to let it recognize and support `multipart/form-data` requests and thus get `getPart()` to work

Submitting an empty field is not the same as not submitting a field.

- If a field is not filled out but submitted, end up as empty strings
- If a field is not submitted at all then its null

so you can check if the value is not just an empty string

```
String file = request.getParameter("file");

if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
    // It's submitted and filled
}
```

You can use accept attribute specifies the types of files that the server accepts (that can be submitted through a file upload).

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

**Note:**

- The accept attribute can only be used with `<input type="file">`
- Do not use this attribute as a validation tool. File uploads should be validated on the server.

**UPDATE**

You can make file upload field mandatory using javascript validation

```js
function validate(){
    var inputField = document.getElementById('upload');
    if(inp.files.length == 0){
        alert("Attachment Required");
        inputField.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="upload">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Take a look at this answer [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: Thanks for your tip with accept=".csv" :) 
Unfortunatly (I tested again with your code), request.getParameter("file") is always null, even when a file is set in my form.
Maybe becuse I'm using enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form...

Comment: Did you annotated your servlet with @MultipartConfig in order to let it recognize and support multipart/form-data requests and thus get getPart() to work ?

Comment: no unfortinaly, this is the same with or without @MultipartConfig.

Comment: Please take a look at the link I shared, It will help you.

Comment: when using `@MultipartConfig` what `req.getPart("file")` returning ?

Comment: It return the right content when I send a file using my form. It throws an exception if my form is empty

Comment: Which exception does it throw?

Comment: A servletException :/ See: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Thanks for your update! But in my case I don't want a mandatory input for my file upload : My page contains multiple forms, and I don't know in advance wich one will be filled by the user. For now I'm using my dirty try/catch technique (posted below)...

Answer (score 0):

A (dirty) way to check if a Part is set,
Since req.getPart("file") throws an exception :

```
boolean isSet = false;
try {
    req.getPart("file");
    isSet = true;
} catch(Exception e) { 
    isSet = false; 
}

if (isSet) {
    // Do your work
}
```